# Create Mono with Map object present within another Mono object

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am new to reactive and not able to get around this.

I have following Dtos:

```
public class User {
    int id;
    Map<String, Car> carsMap;
}

public class Car {
    String carName;
}

// Response object
public class VehiclesInfo {
    List<String> vehicleName;
}
```

From database I am getting `Mono<User>` when querying by userId.

And I have to return `Mono<VehiclesInfo>`.

So, I have to map the `carsMap` received from `Mono<User>` into List i.e. List of carName and set that into VehiclesInfo and return that as Mono i.e. `Mono<VehiclesInfo>`.

I am doing it like below. Please let me know how this can be done without blocking.

```
// userMono is returned by database query 
Mono<User> userMono = getUserInfoById(userId);
Optional<User> userOptional = userMono.blockOptional();

if (userOptional.isPresent()) {
            User user1 = userOptional.get();
            Flux<Car> carFlux = Flux.fromIterable(user1.getCarsMap().keySet())
                    .flatMap(i -> {
                final Car c = new Car();
                c.setCarName(i);
                return Mono.just(c);
            });

            carFlux.subscribe(c -> System.out.println(c.getCarName()));
        }
```

Comment: And what have you tried? Did you read the reactor getting started chapter in the docs?

Comment: @Toerktumlare: I have edited it and shared how I am trying to do it. But. it is blocking. I have checked this link to start https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/

Comment: explain to me what is blocking in the code provided (i want to hear your thought)

Comment: userMono.blockOptional(), I think this will wait for the Mono to emit the result and current thread will be waiting. Please let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: remove the `blockOptional` and do `userMono.flatMap(user -> { ... })` and then remove the if statement. `FlatMap` will only be called if there is something in the Mono. The usage of `flatMap` is covered in the docs that you linked